# Storing the output into one list

Tags: python, list

Here is my code for the question discussed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCeDBWI4sa4
I have not completed writing the final code as I'm stuck half-way.

```
a=list(map(int,input().strip().split())) # takes input as a list
for k in range(0,len(a)):
    b=str(a[k]) #turns each element in the list a into a string
    d=[int(c) for c in str(b)] #divides the digits of one element in the string b, for example, 456 will be divided into three different elements in the list as 4,5,6
    d.sort() #sorts the list in ascending order
    final=[]
    e=d[0]*7+d[-1]*11 #multiplies smallest digit by 7 and largest by 11 and adds the results
    f= list(map(int, str(e))) #turns e into a string, stores each digit as int into the list f
    if len(f)>2: #removes the MSB from the list if number is bigger than 2 digits
        del f[0]
        strings = [str(x) for x in f]  # turns the list into an integer and adds into the list final
        a_string = "".join(strings)
        an_integer = int(a_string)
        final.append(an_integer)
    else:
        strings = [str(x) for x in f] # turns the list into an integer and adds into the list final
        a_string = "".join(strings)
        an_integer = int(a_string)
        final.append(an_integer)
    print(final)
```

I want the list "final" to have all the elements' bit score but I get my output as different lists like so:

```
234 567                                                                                                                       
[58]                                                                                                                          
[12]
```

How do I get the output as:

```
58 12
```

Sorry if the question is confusing. I'm a rookie, easy solutions will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the `final` list above the `for loop`. If you put it below, it will be resetted after every run of the loop.

```
final=[]
a=list(map(int,input().strip().split())) # takes input as a list
for k in range(0,len(a)):
    b=str(a[k]) #turns each element in the list a into a string
    d=[int(c) for c in str(b)] #divides the digits of one element in the string b, for example, 456 will be divided into three different elements in the list as 4,5,6
    d.sort() #sorts the list in ascending order
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realise it was that silly of a mistake. :)

Comment: @SafiyaHamid can you please accept and upvote my answer?

Comment: Already tried to. Says I have to wait for a couple of minutes before I can.

Comment: I was under the impression I could accept two answers, turns out I can't. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are re-creating the empty list `final=[]` each time, don't, and put the print after the loop

Also

- iterate on the list directly, not in the indices
- don't do twice `str` on `str(b)` it is already one
- to check more than 2 digits, it is the same as `>=100` so yoy can use modulo for that
- this avoid doing `int -> list[str] -> str -> int`

```
a = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))  # takes input as a list
final = []
for value in a:
    b = str(value)
    d = [int(c) for c in b]
    d.sort()
    e = d[0] * 7 + d[-1] * 11
    f = e % 100
    final.append(f)
print(final)
```

If you reduce code

```
final = []
for value in a:
    d = sorted([int(c) for c in str(value)])
    e = d[0] * 7 + d[-1] * 11
    final.append(e % 100)
print(final)
```

Comment: @SafiyaHamid I would have thought you'd accept the answer that solve your problem and improve your code , you didn't

Comment: Both your answers were the same, the answer I accepted helped me before your answer did. If I could accept both answers, I would. I can't do that so I accepted the answer that helped me first. Thank you though!

Comment: @SafiyaHamid Just edit my post to improve a lot your code, you do a lot of useless conversion, and tips ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I did realize there was a lot of conversion in my code but didn't know (and bother) to make it easier/shorter/more efficient. Thanks again!